# How do I redirect a user role on login (Drupal 6)?

Tags: routes, users

So I want to create a new user role (already done) and redirect them to a certain page (and use a certain menu) when they log in.

I'm not seeing any specific place to do this under roles or permissions - does it need a third party module? I can give a list of the modules my client is using if that helps.

Note, this is in Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure since I don't have a D6 to test, but you should be able to do this with [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules).

If there's a missing link in rules it's straight forward to code your own condition or action:

- add your [own action](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_action_info/6)
- add your [own condition](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_condition_info/6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rules Module](http://drupal.org/project/rules/)

You can create the redirect after the login.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small piece of code to redirect on login.

```
function hook_user($type, &$edit, &$user, $category = NULL) {
    global $user;
    switch ($type) {
        case 'login':
    if (in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
          drupal_goto(ADMIN_DASHBOARD);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you can do the same using Rules module.
Now to show a Role Based menu you can use [Menu Access Module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_access) to set permissions

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using the [Front Page](http://drupal.org/project/front) module. It does exactly what you need.