# How to direct a specific role to a specific page

Tags: 6, rules

This is related to this question:

[How do I redirect a user role on login (Drupal 6)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36214/how-do-i-redirect-a-user-role-on-login-drupal-6)

My biggest problem is that the only rules available as far as I can see are on user login, period, nothing for a specific role. How would I go about setting the redirect ONLY for certain user roles, when using rules?

Comment: I would have done a write up for this but after a quick google. Everything I was going to cover is on this page: [http://drupal.org/node/683696](http://drupal.org/node/683696). The solution for your specific case seems to be the [login_destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module. If you read in the description; > It is possible to specify certain conditions like referring pages or
> **user roles** and make the destination depend upon them.

Comment: Seems to be for "user" specifically, not a specific user role.

Comment: I edited my answer. Check it out and let me know how it turns out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rules you could select "when a user logs in" and then as the action, select "custom php code" and fiddle with something along the lines of:

```
if (in_array('ROLE_TO_CHECK', array_values($account->roles))) {
  drupal_goto('PAGE_TO_GOTO');
}
```

ADDITION:

D'oh!

Rules can do this....

1. Select 'Add a new rule'
2. Name it whatever and select 'User has logged in' as the event
3. Add a condition: User has role(s)
4. Select the role you want
5. Add an action.
6. Select Page Redirect
7. Enter the path you want ADDITION:  check both Force Redirect and Immediate Issue check boxes
8. Save

Comment: Eek, the only way to do it is with custom code?

Comment: I can do it, but the client might balk at it.

Comment: Does this work in Drupal 6?

Comment: It worked here (D6) with Rules 6.x-1.4