# How to redirect /user to /user/login

Tags: 7, redirection

My client wants the only login url to be /user/login
So I need to redirect /user to /user/login

any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: You should consider that '/user' url can be access by _authenticated_ user also. So, if you redirect '/user' to '/user/login', then its should be redirect to only _anonymous_ user, not _authenticated_ user.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola no problem. but how do i redirect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to direct a specific role to a specific page](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36479/how-to-direct-a-specific-role-to-a-specific-page) - "anonymous" and "authenticated" are roles, too.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module to create a redirect when *anonymous* user view the `/user` page.

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA
>   rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module
>   in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 workflow-ng module.

You can follow below step:

- Go to Administration -> Configuration -> Workflow -> Rules
- Click on *Add new rule* link in top of page
- Fill the *name* and select `Drupal is initializing` from *React on Event* drop down in the form and save the form.
- click on *Add Condition* link in the page and select *User has role(s)* from the "Condition to add" drop-down and select `anonymous user` as user role and save the form.
- Click on *Add condition* link and select "Data comparison" from the "Condition to add" drop-down and set `site:current-page:path` as "Data selector" and click on continue button and set 'user' in the `value` field and save the form.
- Click on *Add Action* link and select `Page redirect` event and set `user/login` in the value field and save the form.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [hook_menu_site_status_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_site_status_alter/7):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_site_status_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_menu_site_status_alter(&$menu_site_status, $path) {
  if (user_is_anonymous()) {
    if ($path == 'user') {
      drupal_goto('user/login');
    }
  }
}
```

Here is [an example](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_menu_site_status_alter/7) on how another module implement this hook.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answer. This only helps someone if they know what to do with the code; it doesn't help them understand why the code solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Refer the https://www.drupal.org/project/rename_admin_paths module. The purpose of this module is to secure drupal backend by overriding admin path.

Option 2: You can also redirect /user to /user/login by writing redirect rule in .htaccess file.